# Is there a good Esperanto cheat sheet about the basic rules?

Tags: learning

I still forget some basic rules of Esperanto. Does anyone have a link to a good  Esperanto cheat sheet?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you are calling "basic rules"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have only ever seen this one [(front)](http://lastranga.tumblr.com/image/150556354707) and [(back)](http://lastranga.tumblr.com/image/150554956187) by Elias N. Jaquez. I will let you decide if it is a good one.

Comment: Mi tre ŝatas ĉi tion, ĉar mi trovas la esperantajn prepoziciojn malfacilajn.

Comment: Very nice one! It is clean and professional looking. I will have to print it and have it laminated.

Answer (score 6):

This is the first bit of Esperanto I ever came across. I guess it qualifies as a cheat sheet.

https://www.esperanto-usa.org/posters/1-page_Handy-Dandy.pdf

Answer (score 6):

There are a few Esperanto cheat sheets out there. I try to share them on my blog whenever I can. But here's one.

http://esperanto.bretonio.free.fr/dokumentoj/pakeo-en2.pdf